# Split a foreach/for loop to make inserts by parts into MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, for-loop, foreach

I have a document with 3 million lines that I have to process and then insert into a table on a database. The database connector class have an insert and an update that receive the data and then make the operation. The insert and update work perfectly.

The problem is that I want to split this modifications to the database to avoid overloading the DB. Ideally I would love to make automatic splits of **n** lines of **arrFinal** and then manage each part separately. But I don't know how to do this.

This is the foreach I have right now:

```
ConnectDB cdb = new ConnectDB();

foreach (string s in arrFinal)
{
    if (s.Split(';')[1] == "REQUEST")
    {
        cdb.Insert(s.Split(';')[0], s.Split(';')[2], s.Split(';')[3], s.Split(';')[4], s.Split(';')[5], dateLog);
    }
    else if (s.Split(';')[1] == "RESPONSE")
    {
        cdb.Update(s.Split(';')[0], s.Split(';')[5]);
    }
}
```

In case you wonder how data comes:

```
00:00:00.7443;REQUEST;POST;https://ulrName/Prices/;/1_0/962;https://ulrName/Prices/1_0/962
00:00:00.7793;RESPONSE;POST;https://ulrName/Prices/;/1_0/962;https://ulrName/Prices/1_0/962
```

Thank you in advance for your help. I'm open to try any approach to get this right.

Comment: Hello.  Assuming arrFinal is your final array with 3 million lines.  If possible, maybe it would be better not collect that many records/lines  in RAM. Instead maybe you could  divide "the reading from document" into smaller jobs with parameters like startingLineIndex and LineCountLimit etc.   Then create function to read pre-determine number of lines and then apply insert/update lines, then read that number of lines again then insert/update etc.  This might be better practice then reading all lines then try and process them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally managed to accomplish what I wanted thanks to this answer in another post:

**[How to split an array into chunks of specific size?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11208003/14521388)**

My final code goes like this:

```
String[][] chunks = arrFinal
                    .Select((s, i) => new { Value = s, Index = i })
                    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 500)
                    .Select(grp => grp.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray())
                    .ToArray();

ConnectDB cdb = new ConnectDB();

for (int i = 0; i < chunks.Length; i++)
{
    foreach (string s in arrFinal)
    {
        var data = s.Split(';'); 
        if (data[1] == "REQUEST")
        {
            cdb.Insert(data[0], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], dateLog);
        }
        else if (data[1] == "RESPONSE")
        {
            cdb.Update(data[0], data[5]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters you really do not need all the `split`s - why recalculate something so many times?

```cs
ConnectDB cdb = new ConnectDB();

foreach (string s in arrFinal)
{
    var data = s.Split(';')
    if (data[1] == "REQUEST")
    {
        cdb.Insert(data[0], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], dateLog);
    }
    else if (data[1] == "RESPONSE")
    {
        cdb.Update(data[0], data[5]);
    }
}
```

You could also use something like [spans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=net-6.0).

As for splitting the array:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int batchSize)
{
    using var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) 
    {
        yield return YieldBatchElements(enumerator, batchSize - 1);
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<T> YieldBatchElements<T>(IEnumerator<T> source, int batchSize)    
{
    yield return source.Current;    for (var i = 0; i < batchSize && source.MoveNext(); i++)    
    yield return source.Current;
}
```

To get all the results at once batched, just append `.ToList()` at the end when using `Batch()` extension method.

Another thing would be to try and load part of the file and process it, then another part, another etc, like AntiqTech [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70259595/split-a-foreach-for-loop-to-make-inserts-by-parts-into-mysql-database#comment124199747_70259595) but it would require some form of saving the current processed amount in case of app failure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, quain!! I've taken a different approach, I'm publishing what worked for me in this case. I also want to thank you for your advice on the many splits I did.