# How to remove the first element in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have an array:

```
arr[0]="a"  
arr[1]="b"  
arr[2]="a"
```

I want to **remove** only `arr[0]`, and **keep** `arr[1]` and `arr[2]`.
I was using:

```
arr= arr.Where(w => w != arr[0]).ToArray();
```

Since `arr[0]` and `arr[2]` have the same value ("a"), the result I'm getting is only `arr[1]`.

How can I return both `arr[1]` and `arr[2]`, and only remove `arr[0]`?

Comment: this is just one of the many reasons a List<T> would be a better choice

Comment: You could have used a different overload that supplies an index: `.Where((w, i) => i > 0)` but `.Skip(1)` would remove the need to even worry about your conditional.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

You can easily do that using `Skip`:

```
arr = arr.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

This creates another array with new elements like in other answers. It's because you can't remove from or add elements to an array. Arrays have a fixed size.

Comment: Yep. Very straight forward.

Comment: Haven't seen this before. Very nice. It's so nice to slowly get to know your tools properly and to learn what functionality they contain. Thanks.

Comment: To use this (and other answers to the question), you need the declaration `using System.Linq;`

Comment: I wish there is an official extension for something like `.DropFirst()`

Answer (score 24):

You could try this:

```
arr = arr.ToList().RemoveAt(0).ToArray();
```

We make a list based on the array we already have, we remove the element in the 0 position and cast
the result to an array.

or this:

```
arr = arr.Where((item, index)=>index!=0).ToArray();
```

where we use the overloaded version of `Where`, which takes as an argument also the item's index. Please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx).

**Update**

Another way, that is more elegant than the above, as [D Stanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081897/d-stanley) pointed out, is to use the `Skip` method:

```
arr = arr.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Comment: The first solution does't work as `RemoveAt(0)` is a procedure and it doesn't return a list so that you can call `ToArray()` on...

Comment: I revoked the last edit because it doesn't improve the answer IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Use second overload of [Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx):-

```
arr = arr.Where((v,i) => i != 0).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

How About:

```
if (arr.Length > 0)
{
    arr = arr.ToList().RemoveAt(0).ToArray();
}
return arr;
```