# Remove item from object Array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, asp.net-core-2.0

I wanted to remove one item from existing object array and generate a separate object array without making the removed item as null in the new object array,

Array:

```
DataSet = new[]
                {
                    new DataSet
                    {
                        Item_1 = "value1",
                        Item_2 = "value2",

                    },
                    new DataSet
                    {
                        Item_1 = "value3",
                        Item_2 = "value4",

                    }
              }
```

Expected result:

```
"DataSet": [
    {
      "Item_1": "value3",
      "Item_2": "value4",

    }
  ]
```

Following code is working as expected:

```
var tempListDataSet = _response.DataSet.ToList();
    tempListDataSet.Remove(_response.DataSet[0]);
    response.DataSet = tempListDataSet.ToArray();
```

Just curious whether there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: Define "better". Would `tempListDataSet.RemoveAt(0)` be "better"?

Comment: @DStanley what is meant was more efficient way having less code

Comment: @SMPH The answer of Nan Yy does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to skip the first one , you can use :

```
var result = _response.DataSet.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Thought this will still create a new array and copy elements since arrays have a fixed size. Thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965131/how-to-remove-the-first-element-in-an-array) is for your reference .

If you want to remove specific element , you could use linq :

```
var result = _response.DataSet.Where((source, index) => index != 1).ToArray();
```

Comment: In case if I want to remove ONLY the second item in the array. Does this work?

Comment: If you want to remove the second item , not the first one ,first two.. you should use removeAt , can't use skip .

Comment: But looks like this is not acceptable `_response.DataSet.ToList().RemoveAt(1).ToArray(); `

Comment: @SMPH :   var result = _response.DataSet.Where((source, index) => index != 1).ToArray();

Comment: @SMPH . Sure . Updated .