# Create a client websocket based console app

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

At the moment I am using REST to consume data from external services/servers using my console app, but it's not very real time.

Can anyone provide a very basic working example of how I can connect a .net core console app to `wss://echo.websocket.org`?

I have started with:

```
using System;
using System.Net.WebSockets;

namespace websocket
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (var ws = new WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org"))
            {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

But `new WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org"))` shows the error `Cannot create an instance of the abstract type or interface 'WebSocket' [websocket]csharp(CS0144)`

Comment: `WebSocket Class` is an abstract class in .Net, And you can't instantiate abstract classes. Please look thits link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocket?view=net-5.0

Comment: Try this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-websockets-in-asp-net-core-day-nine2/ or this link: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-websocket-to-build-real-time-application-via-asp-net-core/ to implement your WebSocket client

Answer (score 15):

If you want to solve your problem using no libraries you'll have to struggle with some internals of .NET.

The following code should provide a simple working solution....

```csharp
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    using (var ws = new ClientWebSocket())
    {
        await ws.ConnectAsync(new Uri("wss://echo.websocket.org"), CancellationToken.None);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        while (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        {
            var result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
            if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
            {
                await ws.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
            }
            else
            {
                HandleMessage(buffer, result.Count);
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void HandleMessage(byte[] buffer, int count)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Received {BitConverter.ToString(buffer, 0, count)}");
}
```

Comment: What "struggles" are you referring to? Your code looks pretty straightforward to me (hence the upvote).

Comment: Use: https://www.piesocket.com/websocket-tester 
for a working wss:// url to test on.

Answer (score 1):

`WebSocket` Class is an abstract class in `.Net`, And you can't instantiate abstract classes.

Please look at this link: [WebSocket Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets.websocket?view=net-5.0).

See these sources just for a guide:

[How To Use WebSockets In ASP.NET Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-websockets-in-asp-net-core-day-nine2/)

[Using WebSocket To Build Real-Time Application Via ASP.NET Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-websocket-to-build-real-time-application-via-asp-net-core/)

[ClientWebSocket example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60178967/3526038)

Answer (score 0):

The code in [WebSockets support in .NET - .NET | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/websockets) works, at least the HTTP/1.1 part. Except for the URI use `wss://echo.websocket.org`.

The following works for me:

```
    Uri uri = new("wss://echo.websocket.org");

    using SocketsHttpHandler handler = new();
    using ClientWebSocket ws = new();
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = new();
    await ws.ConnectAsync(uri, new HttpMessageInvoker(handler), cancellationToken);

    var bytes = new byte[1024];
    System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketReceiveResult result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(bytes, default);
    string res = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, result.Count);

    await ws.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "Client closed", default);
    Console.WriteLine($"Result ({result.Count} bytes): {res}");
```