# Sub-arrays and ranges in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm working with some data that is best stored as arrays, and I often have to work with sub-arrays and ranges. What I would like is something like this:

```
int[] src = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3}
int[] sub = src+2;
```

'sub' would then not be a deep copy, but rather a reference to a specific offset into the 'src' array. Edit: Array safety, such as overflows, could be checked by the original array in this instance.

While this specific utility would be trivial for me to write, are there already standard solutions or third-party libraries that provide this functionality? I don't want to recreate the wheel and, if there are other such classes available, I'd rather build on their work (as they might provide much more functionality that I didn't even think I needed).

Comment: What is the desired result of `int[] sub = src+2;`, please?

Comment: If you referenced sub[0], you would get src[2]; sub[1] would be src[3], etc

Comment: How about [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4600024/69809)?

Comment: There's an specific class for that purpose, ArraySegment.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. All my searches returned copies and clones, which weren't what I wanted.