# C# sub-array without memory allocations (copying)

Tags: c#, arrays

Is it possible in C# to make temporary sub-array on top of existent array without memory allocations/copying?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ArraySegment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) structure:

> Delimits a section of a one-dimensional array.

Take also a look at this question: [what is the use of ArraySegment class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600024/what-is-the-use-of-arraysegmentt-class)

Here's an example usage, stolen from Stephen Kennedy's answer:

```
var array = new byte[] { 5, 8, 9, 20, 70, 44, 2, 4 };
array.Dump();
var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(array, 2, 3);
segment.Dump(); // output: 9, 20, 70
segment.Reverse().Dump(); // output 70, 20, 9
segment.Any(s => s == 99).Dump(); // output false
segment.First().Dump(); // output 9
array.Dump(); // no change
```

Comment: new ArraySegment is already a allocation action