# C# - Code optimization to get all substrings from a string

Tags: c#, optimization

I was working on a code snippet to get all substrings from a given string.

Here is the code that I use

```
 var stringList = new List<string>();
 for (int length = 1; length < mainString.Length; length++)
 {
    for (int start = 0; start <= mainString.Length - length; start++)
    {
       var substring = mainString.Substring(start, length);
       stringList.Add(substring);
    }
 }
```

It looks not so great to me, with two for loops. Is there any other way that I can achieve this with better time complexity.

I am stuck on the point that, for getting a substring, I will surely need two loops. Is there any other way I can look into ?

Comment: Use substring method, Even you are writing wrong for loop . Code is missing

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What do you intend to do with all those substrings?

Comment: Every possible sub string from an given input?

Comment: @MichaelRandall Yes. Exactly

Comment: @Shyamsundarshah I have added mainString.Substring(start, length). Where exactly is the code missing ?

Comment: @PraneetNadkar, don't forget to accept an answer.

Answer (score 9):

The number of substrings in a string is `O(n^2)`, so one loop inside another is the best you can do. You are correct in your code structure.

Here's how I would've phrased your code:

```
void Main()
{
    var stringList = new List<string>();
    string s = "1234";
    for (int i=0; i <s.Length; i++)
        for (int j=i; j < s.Length; j++)
            stringList.Add(s.Substring(i,j-i+1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you Phillip !

Comment: So there is no way we can improve O(n^2)?

Comment: No you can't improve O(n^2), because there are exactly (n(n+1))/2 substrings, which in Big O notation is O(n^2). The number of answers sets the lower bound of the complexity, so you can't improve on it.

Comment: I get it. Thank you @phillip-ngan

Answer (score 4):

You do need 2 `for` loops

[Demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7ZjqpU)

```
var input = "asd sdf dfg";
var stringList = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = i; j < input.Length; j++)
    {
        var substring = input.Substring(i, j-i+1);
        stringList.Add(substring);
    }
}

foreach(var item in stringList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

**Update**

You cannot improve on the iterations.

However you can improve performance, by using `fixed` arrays and pointers

Comment: Thanks for the effort Michael !
I am just wondering if there is any way we can improve the time complexity. Here, it would be same as that of the method I wrote

Comment: @PraneetNadkar there is not

Comment: Thanks Michael :)

Answer (score 2):

In some cases you can significantly increase execution speed by reducing object allocations. In this case by using a single `char[]` and [`ArraySegment<of char>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d(v=vs.110).aspx) to process substrings. This will also lead to use of less address space and decrease in garbage collector load.

Relevant excerpt from [Using the StringBuilder Class in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder) page on Microsoft Docs:

> The [String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string) object is immutable. Every time you use one of the methods in the [System.String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string) class, you create a new string object in memory, which requires a new allocation of space for that new object. In situations where you need to perform repeated modifications to a string, the overhead associated with creating a new [String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string) object can be costly.

Example implementation:

```
static List<ArraySegment<char>> SubstringsOf(char[] value)
{
    var substrings = new List<ArraySegment<char>>(capacity: value.Length * (value.Length + 1) / 2 - 1);
    for (int length = 1; length < value.Length; length++)
        for (int start = 0; start <= value.Length - length; start++)
            substrings.Add(new ArraySegment<char>(value, start, length));
    return substrings;
}
```

For more information check [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals) page on Microsoft Docs, [what is the use of ArraySegment class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600024/what-is-the-use-of-arraysegmentt-class) discussion on StackOverflow, [ArraySegment<T> Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN and [List<T>.Capacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks Leonid !
May I know if this ArraySegment<char> would be faster than List<string> in terms of search or insert ?

Comment: They are used for different purposes. An `ArraySegment<of char>` represents a single substring and a `List<of string>` represents a set of substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `O(n**2)` *time* complexity is inevitable, however you can try impove *space* consumption. In many cases, you don't want all the substrings being *materialized*, say, as a `List<string>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> AllSubstrings(string value) {
  if (value == null) 
    yield break; // Or throw ArgumentNullException

  for (int length = 1; length < value.Length; ++length)
    for (int start = 0; start <= value.Length - length; ++start)
      yield return value.Substring(start, length);
}
```

For instance, let's count all substrings in `"abracadabra"` which start from `a` and longer than `3` characters. Please, notice that all we have to do is to *loop* over susbstrings *without* saving them into a list:

```
int count = AllSubstrings("abracadabra")
  .Count(item => item.StartsWith("a") && item.Length > 3);
```

If for any reason you want a `List<string>`, just add `.ToList()`:

```
var stringList = AllSubstrings(mainString).ToList();
```

Comment: Probably `if (AllSubstrings("abracadabra").Any("abc")) { ... }` is not the best example because it is equivalent to `if ("abracadabra".Contains("abc")) { ... }`, which is much faster and more readable.

Comment: @Leonid Vasilyev: Quite agree, thank you! I've providede a more complicated example (which is not that easy to implement, in a single line)

Comment: Depending on how the `Substring` method is implemented this could be O(N^3)