# How do I get a byte array from an ArraySegment

Tags: c#

If someone passes me an `ArraySegment<byte> foo` and this segment points into a larger buffer, what's the idiomatic way to copy this segment into a fresh new `byte[]` ?

I tried accessing at `foo.Array` but this seems to point to the beginning of the larger buffer, not the beginning of the segment.

e.g. the larger buffer could be "blahfoobar" and the ArraySegment points to "foo". I want to get a `byte[]` with just "foo".

I'm sure it's dead simple, but coming from C++, I can't figure the lingo used in c#.

Comment: I see ArraySegment implements the ICollection, so you have to have the ToArray method

Comment: @PiGi78 that's only true with .Net 4.5 and above and .Net Core and it implements heaps more iterative types than ICollection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7907024/495455 - OP looks like you need iterate through the ArraySegments converting ToArray and joining the arrays together.

Answer (score 4):

Creating a new array would be entirely to miss the point of the API, which is to represent a pre-existing segment. In more recent .NET version, `Span<T>` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>` would be better choices - they allow you to create an abstraction over contiguous memory without needing the consumer to worry about the `Offset` etc, as that can be imposed externally. There are constructors on `Span<T>` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>` that allow you to deal with aspects so that the consumer never needs to know about them, with the knowledge that on recent runtimes: the JIT will elide bounds checks on spans.

Comment: awesome. I'll look at my version see if span would fit. I'm familiar with C++ gsl::span and like them

Comment: @Jeffrey note: if you need to store the range as a field on the heap, you'll need [ReadOnly]Memory-T; memory is basically "I can give you a span when you need it" - it could just as easily have been called "SpanSource" or similar. You can create a memory over an array segment (and a range of other things, including custom allocators)

Answer (score 1):

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly byte[] _initArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("blahfoobar");

        //private static byte[] ArraySegmentToArray(ArraySegment<byte> segment)
        //{
        //    var result = new byte[segment.Count];

        //    for (int i = 0; i < segment.Count; i++)
        //    {
        //        result[i] = segment.Array[i + segment.Offset];
        //    }

        //    return result;
        //}

        private static byte[] ArraySegmentToArray(ArraySegment<byte> segment) =>
            segment.ToArray();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var segFoo = new ArraySegment<byte>(_initArray, 4, 3);

            var test = ArraySegmentToArray(segFoo);
        }
    }
}
```

But of course it is bad practice. Because if you turn segment to array you allocate memory, and if you use ArraySegment stuff as pointers , you don't allocate memory, actually, that is the main idea of using ArraySegment, because if not the array could be provided as parameters :)
P.S. Commented code just for understanding the idea.

Comment: That helps. I like the fact that it shows `segment.Offset` being explicitly needed from `.Array[]`. But there has to be a way to directly get an offset'ed array, no?

Comment: What's the runtime cost of `ToArray` ? Please confirm it's returning the existing memory, not making a copy

Comment: @Jeffrey OP requested "into a fresh new byte[] ?" which indeed this code does. Not sure why you think it should do something else... How you can create new array without newly allocated space for it? It does not work that way even in C++ which you claim to know...

Comment: Runtime cost is allocation = bytes x number of requests + code execution:) If you use ArraySegment properly then only code execution.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov what OP (and myself) meant by "fresh new byte[]" was something that behave like an array at the offset position. As in `char* fresh = original + offset;` this doesn't allocate memory. `ToArray()` works for me, because the rest of the code expect a byte[]. It's unfortunate that it allocate a copy.